# INNER JOIN with GROUP BY the CakePHP way

Tags: php, cakephp, group-by, inner-join

I'm writing a plug-in module for a system that uses CakePHP 1.2 and I am new to the framework. How does one do the following query the Cake way?

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(a.id) AS comments
FROM articles a LEFT JOIN comments c ON a.id = c.item_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY comments DESC;
```

I can't edit the Article or Comment models, but I'm trying this in my plug-in's model and it doesn't give the same result:

```
$this->loadModel('Article');
$options['fields'] = array('Article.id', 'Article.name', 
              'COUNT(Article.id) AS comments');
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'comments',
          'alias' => 'c',
          'type' => 'INNER',
          'conditions' => array(
          'Article.id = c.item_id')
         ));
$options['group'] = array('Article.id');
$options['order'] = 'comments DESC';
$options['limit'] = 5;
$rows = $this->Article->find('all', $options);
```

Also, I'm not sure but I think the Article class might already have:

```
 public $actsAs = array('Containable');
 public $hasMany = array('Comment');
```

Comment: In your plain sql you have a `LEFT JOIN`, in the Cake you define `type => INNER`. Is it intentional?

Comment: I believe INNER is more correct and you use LEFT and RIGHT only with OUTER joins, but in my experience MySQL treats JOIN, LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN all identical

Comment: No, `INNER` and `LEFT` (`LEFT OUTER`) joins are treated differently. However mysql will trat a `LEFT JOIN` as an `INNER JOIN` if you add further conditions on the joined table to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `INNER` vs `LEFT`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very unexpected answer:

The version of CakePHP used by this project (which I can do nothing about) is version 1.2.0.6311 beta released on 2008-01-02 and according to [this article](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/06/03/new-way-to-group-by-in-cakephp) the group by functionality in Cake's model find method was only added in May 2008

Comment: Ha! I'd never figure that one out! So you'll have to update Cake, or forget about the "cake way" and simply run your query with `Model::query`.

Comment: Yes, I sanitize my parameters and use $this->query(...)

Answer (score 3):

I think you also need to add `foreignKey => FALSE` to your join definition:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'comments',
          'alias' => 'c',
          'type' => 'INNER',
          'foreignKey' => FALSE,
          'conditions' => array('Article.id = c.item_id')
     )
);
```

Also, if you are forcing the joins yourself, you should get rid of any previous Cake-style associations, either by passing `recursive => FALSE` as an options, or by applying [`unbindModel`](http://api12.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelunbindModel) to each associated model.

**UPDATE**

Based on what you said in the comments, here is what I think you need:

```
$options['fields'] = array(
    'Article.id', 
    'Article.name', 
    'COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS comments'
);
$options['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'comments',
        'alias' => 'c',
        'type' => 'LEFT OUTER',
        'foreignKey' => FALSE,
        'conditions' => array('Article.id = c.item_id')
    )
);
$options['group'] = array('Article.id');
$options['order'] = 'COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) DESC';
$rows = $this->Article->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: Sorry to report that I have tried all three suggestions with no luck. Only one row is returned and it has the wrong comment count.

Comment: +1 for the LEFT OUTER join. It didn't solve my problem, but it is a better query for my use case